# Why is the "type parameter never used" even though it is used in a where clause?

Tags: generics, rust

I am quite new to Rust, and I keep crossing with this issue, and I don't know how to go around it. I have a struct like,

```
pub struct Solver <'e, E: 'e, T, M, C>
    where
        E: Equation<T, M, C>,
        T: Term<C>,
        M: Mesh,
{
    equations: &'e [E],
}
```

that is always giving me this error,

```
error[E0392]: parameter `T` is never used
 --> src\solver.rs:5:31
  |
5 | pub struct Solver <'e, E: 'e, T, M, C>
  |                               ^ unused parameter
  |
  = help: consider removing `T`, referring to it in a field, or using a marker such as `PhantomData`
```

I understand that `T` is never used, but, for instance, I can't define Equation without `T` (or can I?). Is there a shorter version to write it?
This `PhantomData` is a strange thing I would like to avoid, so I don't know how to solve this.

Comment: What happens when you remove `T`?

Comment: Use  `PhantomData` - it exists for that purpose

Comment: If I remove from the `Solver` line, the `Equation<T..>` have issues and no way to declare `T: Term`.

Comment: Thanks, @SvetlinZarev, I was fearing it would be a bad implementation that led me to need to this and I was hoping there would be a better way of doing so. But you are probably right. :)

Comment: Before you go adding phantom data every time you get this error, consider whether your generic structs really use any instances of the types the compiler is complaining about. I suggest you build up your traits and structs incrementally, and only add generic parameters as you need them. The compiler is complaining because it doesn't see any usage of a generic param in any of the method signatures or fields. IN a lot of cases, for traits, you don't have to add all the types that implementors will need to use.. that can be left up to the implementing classes unless it's a type shared by all.

Comment: There's no harm using PhantomData where you need to and even if you don't. But I see them used pretty sparingly and only where there's good justification. They shouldn't be a default goto to satisfy the complier.

Comment: @Todd, that's my feeling too, it sounds a bit like the `null` solution, that's why my effort in avoiding it. :)

Comment: There *is* harm in using `PhantomData`, since it limits how the type can be used. This may cause confusing Heisenbugs that pop up in other places as well as being a backwards compatibility hazard. If you don't know whether to use `PhantomData<T>`, `PhantomData<fn(T)>`, `PhantomData<fn() -> T>`, `PhantomData<fn(T) -> T>`, `PhantomData<*const T>` or `PhantomData<*mut T>`, **you should not use `PhantomData` at all.**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When bounding types for generics, bounds only make sense to the compiler where the features of the bounding types are used (calling their methods or accessing their fields, etc). It's not often necessary to constrain things otherwise. There are reasons to do it, but it's good to add those in only when the need is realized. And when declaring generic parameters, the same applies. Unless there's an explicit use of that parameter within the struct, it may not need to be added regardless whether the `impl` may need it.

In the code below, `Solver` isn't doing anything with `E` except holding it in an array, so that could be any type. It's flexible.

```rust
pub trait Equation
{
    type T;
    fn eq(&self) -> Self::T;
}

pub struct Solver<'e, E: 'e>
{
    equations: &'e [E],
}

impl<'e, E: 'e> Solver<'e, E>
{
    fn get_e(&self, i: usize) -> &'e E
    {
        &self.equations[i]
    }
}
```

Now suppose `Solver` will need to invoke the `eq()` method on the `E`'s in its array. Still, so far it's not necessary to put bounds on `E` yet in the struct definition. The bounds only have meaning in the implementation.

```rust
pub struct Solver<'e, E: 'e>
{
    equations: &'e [E],
}

impl<'e, E: 'e, F> Solver<'e, E>
where 
    E: Equation<T = F>,
{
    fn get_e(&self, i: usize) -> &'e E
    {
        &self.equations[i]
    }
    fn e_eq(&self, i: usize) -> F
    {
        self.equations[i].eq()
    }
}
```

The above will compile fine. The struct only cares that it has an `E` of any type and its lifetime adheres to `'e`. And the `impl` became a little more specific by necessity.

The `impl` for structs can be somewhat independent in this regard. We didn't add any constraints until there was a need that arose from invoking `.eq()` and doing something with its return type. And a new generic parameter was added, because it had to be - there's an immediate use of it and the compiler will be satisfied.

Above, the specific type returned by `.eq()` was deferred to generic parameter `F`. So far, `Solver` can take any `E` that returns any type `T` as yet undefined - which is associated with `Solver`'s `F` - and return it from `e_eq()`.

To constrain things more and ensure that any `E` that `Solver` takes returns an `i32` from its `eq()` method, `F` can be eliminated, and the type specified in the bounds of `E`:

```rust
impl<'e, E: 'e> Solver<'e, E>
where 
    E: Equation<T = i32>,
{
    fn get_e(&self, i: usize) -> &'e E
    {
        &self.equations[i]
    }
    fn e_eq(&self, i: usize) -> i32
    {
        self.equations[i].eq()
    }
}
```

All the changes so far have been by necessity and haven't affected the definition of `Solver`'s struct - just the `impl`.

I've personally found deferring things like this to be a good approach. Incrementally adding bounds as they're required, while continually ensuring that the code builds each step of the way can save time, as opposed to declaring several things ahead of time. If I think of several things that need to be added, I put them in TODO comments and work the changes in one at a time.

If you're working from a design doc of some sort while teammates are implementing things that will be dependent on the pieces you provide, you can add the needed methods to the `impl` and work in the bounds as they're needed and leave the method bodies empty with an `unimplemented!()` macro in them. Let the compiler give you hints on what bounds you need to add in as you go.

Strict constraints in the `struct` declaration may only be required when there are public fields, and other parts of the program make assumptions about what interfaces or properties those fields support.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`PhantomData`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/struct.PhantomData.html), from the documentation:

> Zero-sized type used to mark things that “act like” they own a T.
>
> Adding a PhantomData field to your type tells the compiler that
> your type acts as though it stores a value of type T, even though it
> doesn’t really. This information is used when computing certain safety
> properties.

```rust
struct Solver <'e, E: 'e, T, M, C>
    where
        E: Equation<T, M, C>,
        T: Term<C>,
        M: Mesh,
{
    equations: &'e [E],
    _phantom_t: PhantomData<T>,
    _phantom_m: PhantomData<M>,
    _phantom_c: PhantomData<C>
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=494f5a11fb2c584b8c669a47f71e902c)